# ios storyboard place a view to right of the middle of superview

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Search a bit but could not find a solution. 
Suppose I have a label and a text field. I want the textfield to be aligned 10 pixel to the right of middle of its superview having a width of half of superview - 20 pixel. i.e. 10 px gap in both side. 
How can I achieve that in storyboard? Is it possible or I have write code for that?
Similarly Label is half of superview - 20 px width. Left aligned. 10 px left gap.

Comment: What I would do (not sure if it's the best way to do it), I would add a view with the width of 1px horizontally centered  to the superview and then I would align the two views relative to this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this with both views having the same width?

```
|-10-[UILabel]-20-[UITextField]-10-|
```

Then one way to go about this is to create constraints for

- leading margin for `UILabel`
- horizontal spacing between `UILabel` and `UITextField`
- trailing margin for `UITextField`
- same width of `UILabel` and `UITextField`

Answer (score 5):

- So:

> I want the textfield to be aligned 10 pixel to the right of middle of its superview
>   That could be done like that:
>   [image]
>   Horizontal centering constraint with offset to the right.

- And now

> having a width of half of superview - 20 pixel. i.e. 10 px gap in both side.

To achieve that you should select your parent view and your subview(in your case, the text field) by holding the command key and left-clicking both you view and the text field.
See the image below:

[image]

Having those two selected, click the Pin button at the bottom of the IB editor area and make all as illustrated below:
[image]

Then, go to the inspector area of either your parent view or your text field and make it be like (the image is captured from the text field's inspector). And notice: you should select the equal width constraint and type the values manually. When you change the multiplier from 1 to 0.5, the constraint will become of type "proportional width" and that is what you are eager for.

[image]

- Setting right margins and horizontal inter-space should not be a problem. Enjoy coding, man :)

Comment: Thanks. upvoted. I did it this way on first try. Your answer is very good with screenshots. But the super view's edge insect gave me some trouble. @Jakub s answer is easier and did my work. :)

Comment: It ended good anyways, thanks for being grateful :) I just didn't know you want both the text field and the label to have the same width, as typically captions of text fields are much shorter than the text fields. Good luck :)

Comment: You were right. I had no restriction on label's size. But for now equal width serves me well.

Answer (score 1):

if i got you right this is totally possible in storyboard. setup the following constraints:

1. pin the labels leading to the leading of its superview with a constant of 10
2. pin the labels trailing to the leading of the textfield with a constant of 20
3. pin the textfields trailing to the trailing of its superview with a constant of 10
4. create an equal widths constraint for the label and the textfield

hope i got you right :)